# acceder a variables de una colección laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Hola les comento mi problema:
Tengo una tabla datos_superficie y otra superficie,un formulario donde cargo datos que obtengo desde datos_superficie, en donde el usuario realizará un tipo de filtro, busco los datos en la bd en la tabla superficie según lo que coloque el usuario,para finalmente colocar esos datos en la tabla superficies, pero cuando obtengo los datos no se como acceder a ellos

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Super;
use App\DatoSuperficie;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SuperController extends Controller
{
    public function transform(){

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $cod_uso_suelo = $request->cod_uso_suelo;
        //dd($cod_uso_suelo);
        $datos = ['cod_pais', 'cod_fundo','nom_fundo'];
        $datoSuperficie = DatoSuperficie::where('cod_uso_suelo','=',$cod_uso_suelo)->get();

        dd($datoSuperficie);

        //Super::create($datoSuperficie);

      }  
}
```

Si imprimo la variable $datoSuperficie me muestra lo sgte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si agrego e imprimo por ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
$cod_pais = $datoSuperficie->cod_pais;
```

me muestra el siguiente error:

```
"Property [cod_pais] does not exist on this collection instance."
```

Viendo el collection se qe quiero acceder a un array dentro de un array, quizás ahí mi error, solo hace unos días comencé con laravel, aún no tengo claro como hacer esto :(
*Uso laravel 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando utilizas la función `get()` de Eloquent, te trae un array de elementos, asi sea solo 1.

Para acceder a cada uno es necesario colocar un indice o tratarlo como array de esta forma

```
dd($datoSuperficie[0]->id);

foreach($datoSuperficie as $dato) {
    dump($dato->id);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, se arreglo con ese for :D

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso queria utilizar una variable de mi consulta anteriror y utilice first() en vez de get();

```
$useracceso=Sucursalacceso::select('AccesarOtrasSucursalesEnLinea as sucursalacceso','sucursal')->where('usuario',$user->usuario)->first();
```